# failed to send opt code with firebase phone authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I wrote a flutter app that have a phone authentication with firebase and when I am sending the phone number the verification request keep failing. Someone know what wrong with my code or how can I fix it?.

- I am sending the phone number as is (without the area code) (the "phoneNumber" variable). does it ok?
- I need to change any settings in firebase accept turning on the phone authentication option?

Thank you.

this is my code (the verification part):

```
// imports...

enum Status { waiting, error }

class VerificationCode extends StatefulWidget {
  const VerificationCode({Key? key, this.number}) : super(key: key);
  final number;
  @override
  _VerificationCodeState createState() => _VerificationCodeState(number);
}

class _VerificationCodeState extends State<VerificationCode> {
  late final phoneNumber;
  final _verKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late String _verCode;
  late double _formHeight;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var _verificationId;
  var _status = Status.waiting;
  _VerificationCodeState(this.phoneNumber);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
  }

  Future _verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) async {
    print(phoneNumber);
    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber, // phoneNumber
        verificationCompleted: (phonesAuthCredentials) async {},
        verificationFailed: (verificationFailed) async {
          print("failed"); // here the code fall.
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, reseningToken) async {
          setState(() {
            _verificationId = verificationId;
            print(_verificationId);
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) async {});
  }

  Future _sendCodeToFirebase({String? code}) async {
    if (_verificationId != null) {
      var credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _verificationId,
        smsCode: code!,
      );

      await _auth
          .signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then((value) {
            print("auth complete!");
          })
          .whenComplete(() {})
          .onError((error, stackTrace) {
            setState(() {
              _verKey.currentState!.reset();
              _status = Status.error;
            });
          });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (size.height <= 736) {
      _formHeight = (size.height * .05) + 6;
    } else {
      _formHeight = size.height * .048;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
            FocusNode(),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: size.height - 90,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: size.height * .006,
                            left: size.width * .03,
                          ),
                          child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/arrow-back.svg",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: size.height * .18,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "AppName",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: size.width * .096,
                          letterSpacing: size.width * .026,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * .015),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: size.width * .045,
                        ),
                        height: _formHeight,
                        child: Form(
                          key: _verKey,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: size.width * .035,
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              counterText: "",
                              contentPadding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                              hintText: 'Verification Code',
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  width: 1.25,
                                ),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  width: 1.5,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            autofocus: false,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            cursorColor: Colors.black,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            onChanged: (input) async {
                              if (input.length == 6) {
                                _verCode = input;
                                _sendCodeToFirebase(code: _verCode);
                              }
                            },
                            maxLength: 6,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.height * .006),
                    child: Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Text(
                          "Resend code",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontSize: size.width * .034,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          _verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending OTP in firebase you would need to add your area code along with the 10 digit phone number for it to send successfully.

Example From Firebase Docs:

```
phoneNumber: '+447123123456'
```

Here's the documentation for using firebase in flutter:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone